# Number of pairs that create a real number when placed in the exponent of complex number i

Tags: python-2.7

In my intro Python class, we're exploring the use of complex numbers. I'm asked to use for loops to find the number of pairs of variables x and y that, for a given value of N, satisfy the conditions

```
a) 0 <= x < y <= N  and

b) i^x + i^y is a real number (not complex)
```

Since the value of i is sqrt(-1), this happens only when x and y are even numbers:

```
sqrt(-1)^0 = 1 => this is real

sqrt(-1)^1 = sqrt(-1) => this is complex

sqrt(-1)^2 = -1 => this is real

sqrt(-1)^3 = -sqrt(-1) => this is complex
```

and so on

So, I've written code as follows

```
a1 = 0
N = int(raw_input('Please select a value for N: '))
for x in range(0, N):
    for y in range(x+1, N+1):
        if x%2==0 and y%2==0:
            a1 = a1+1
```

This utilizes the mod operator to determine whether the values for x and y are even or odd, and, if both values are even, it advances the count variable a1 by 1. It is given to us that for N = 100, our total count, what I have as a1, should be 1900. However, at the end of my loop, my a1 is 1275. I'm having trouble analyzing the code to determine where the error is.

Comment: I dont get how your title matches your problem though

Comment: Your title does not seem remotely related to your question body.

Comment: I apologize - I was typing over an old question and forgot to update the title

Comment: "Since the value of i is sqrt(-1), this happens only when x and y are even numbers" - nope. You're missing a possibility.

Comment: If you mean I'm overlooking x = 0, I'm including 0 as an even number by my definition that x%2 = 0. Otherwise, what am I overlooking? For any x greater than or equal to 0, i^x can only be 1, i, -1, or -i, for which 1 only occurs for x = 0 and -1 only occurs on any even value of x

Comment: Unless you're adding i and -i, of course.

Comment: *facepalm* thank you, Ignacio. I will go back to work on it realizing that option as well